# PHP same [ ] for array

Tags: php, mysql

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEy50.png)

Hello, as you see, indexes for both arrays is 0, how can I call "text 1" and "text 2" independently ?

Thank you.

Code is

```
$command2 = $db->prepare("SELECT text from khma where id IN (97,98)");
$command2->execute();
$result2 = $command2->fetchAll();
foreach ($result2 as $key ) {
    print_r($key);
}
```

Comment: Include the code in your post and please, take the [tour].

Comment: Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: sorry fellas, updated.

Comment: Database libraries commonly return result sets with both numeric and text keys for each row - you can safely ignore the numeric ones (or pass in the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` constant if you really don't want them). Just refer to the columns by name.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetchAll will return result-set as an associative array and numeric array. You can just ignore the numeric array value. If you need to get only associate array you need to pass `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in fetch

```
  $result = $command2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
   print $value['text'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. $result2[0]['text'] does the job without any foreacheas